# regsvr32 access denied in a specific folder

Tags: windows, com, regsvr32

I get an error when running `regsvr32` on a particular DLL, in a particular folder (see attached image).

[image: Regsvr32 reports Access denied]

The curious thing is that the error is "Access Denied", and if I copy the DLL to a different empty folder in `C:\Temp` it works okay.

Has anyone ever heard of such a problem?

I know you need Admin rights, and am running a command shell As Administrator.

Comment: I would suggest using [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) to see what exact operation is failing.

Comment: Thanks, but what would I be looking for?  Regsvr32 is what is failing.

Comment: Look for what it is doing that failed with "access denied."

Answer (score 0):

To close this out, and in case anyone else has a similar problem.
It turned out that access really was denied for the dll I was trying to register. Specifically, I had read access but not "Read and execute".
The source of that problem was because I had added the compiled dll to git, and when Jenkins was retrieving it, it ended up without "Read and execute" permission.  Removing the dll from git control fixed that particular problem for me.